# Prepositions: to stay in or at a place during/on/for/in a holiday

Tags: prepositions

I don't really know if there is a difference in the meaning of the sentences below. For me as a not native speaker it kind of expresses the same idea. 
Or maybe not?

> I stayed at/in a hotel for/during/on/in my last holiday.(Here any preposition sounds correct to me)
>
> ---
>
> I stayed in/at a camper... (Here "at" sounds wrong to me)

Thanks a lot :)

NGram:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=in+my+holiday%2Cduring+my+holiday%2Con+my+holiday%2Cfor+my+holiday%2C+whilst+my+holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20my%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20my%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20my%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20my%20holiday%3B%2Cc

Answer (score 1):

If this is a question of "at" vs "in" then the common difference is that "in" implies "inside" and limited to an enclosed space whereas "at" implies a region or some area. But this is a very thin description.

You can't say "I stayed at his room" since "room" is an enclosed area, but you can say either "at the hotel (meaning the vicinity too)" or "in the hotel (mostly referring to your accommodation)".